# "VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update" warning even though all components are optimized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've been having lots of trouble trying to avoid getting the "VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update" warning when using a `<FlatList>` component with React-Native.

I've already done loads of research and Google-Fu to try a solution, but none of the solutions helped, not even the solution on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13649).

Things to keep in mind:

- I'm using `shouldComponentUpdate() { return false; }` in my List Item component, so they are not updating at all.
- The component that renders the FlatList is already a `PureComponent`
- I added console.logs in the render methods of my components and can confirm they don't re-render.
- I'm not using anonymous functions, so the `renderItem` component is not being re-initialized on each call.

**Important**: The warning only seems to occur after switching to a separate tab using my `BottomTabNavigator` and then coming back and scrolling through my list; but this is confusing because when I do this, the FlatList screen component is not re-rendering and neither are the list items. Since the components aren't re-rendering when browsing to another tab, why would this error happen?

Here's my exact code:

*App.tsx*

```
const AppRoutes = [
  { name: "Home", Component: HomeScreen },
  { name: "Catalog", Component: CatalogScreen },
  { name: "Cart", Component: CartScreen }
];

export const StoreApp = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <Tabs.Navigator>
        {AppRoutes.map((route, index) => 
          <Tabs.Screen
            key={index}
            name={route.name}
            component={route.Component}
            options={{
              headerShown: (route.name !== "Home") ?? false,
              tabBarIcon: props => <TabIcon icon={route.name} {...props} />
            }}
          />
        )}
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

*CatalogScreen.tsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, Text, View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { LoadingSpinnerOverlay } from "../components/LoadingSpinnerOverlay";
import { getAllProducts, ProductListData } from "../api/catalog";

class ProductItem extends React.Component<{ item: ProductListData }> {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {console.log(`Rendered ${this.props.item.name}-${Math.random()}`)}
        <Text style={{height: 100}}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class CatalogScreen extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    productData: []
  };
  
  componentDidMount() {
    getAllProducts()
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ productData: response.data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  private renderItem = (props: any) => <ProductItem {...props} />;
  private keyExtractor = (product: any) => `${product.id}`;
  private listItemLayout = (data: any, index: number) => ({
    length: 100,
    offset: 100 * index,
    index
  });

  render() {
    const { productData } = this.state;
    console.log("CATALOG RENDERED");

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.pageView}>
        {!productData.length && <LoadingSpinnerOverlay text="Loading products..." />}
        <View style={{backgroundColor: "red", height: "50%"}}>
          <FlatList
            data={productData}
            removeClippedSubviews
            keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            getItemLayout={this.listItemLayout}
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pageView: {
    height: "100%",
    position: "relative",
  }
});
```

Since my components and lists are optimized and I'm still receiving the error, I'm starting to believe that this may be an actual issue with React Native - but if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, or any workarounds, this would help greatly!

**Additional Findings:**
I found that the warning no longer occurs if the `CatalogScreen` component is contained inside of a `NativeStackNavigator` with a single Screen. I believe this may indicate that this is a problem with the `BottomTabNavigator` module.

For example, the no warning no longer occurs if I make the following changes:

*App.tsx*

```
const AppRoutes = [
  { name: "Home", Component: HomeScreen },
  { name: "Catalog", Component: CatalogPage }, // Changed CatalogScreen to CatalogPage
  { name: "Cart", Component: CartScreen }
];
```

*CatalogScreen.tsx*

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export class CatalogPage extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="CatalogStack" 
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
          component={CatalogScreen}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

With this workaround, I'm rendering the Stack Navigation component instead of the `CatalogScreen` component directly. This resolves the problem, but I don't understand why this would make a difference. Does React Native handle memory objects differently in Stack Navigation screens as opposed to BottomTabNavigator screens?

Comment: How is your "CATALOG RENDERED" not logging twice, from what I can see it has to render twice, you're rendering everything, then triggering a state update after the component has been mounted, which should trigger another render.  The fact that you say it doesn't render twice is an issue, the only reason it wouldn't render twice is if it's catching an error and logging it instead of updating the product state.

Comment: Is there any improvement if you add the getItemLayout to the FlatList component? Or your components are of variable dimensions?

Comment: @Matriarx I apologize, yes, it renders once initially and renders again after the API data is fetched - however, it does not render again at any point after that, even when switching tabs on my BottomTabNavigator.

Comment: @joseluismurillorios I appreciate the idea! I actually did try this after making this post and it didn't make a difference. Each list item is 100 points in height. What's weird is I only get the error after switching to another tab, coming back, and then start scrolling on the list.

Comment: It is weird that it only happens after switching tabs, because then my instinct is to say it's becasue of rendering again.  But you say it doesn't render again after you've switched tabs, which is strange.  Try making your components all pure views and if you can use memo on the parent, see if that helps.  If something is triggering a render, even if it's not showing in console, perhaps pure/memo will prevent it.

Comment: @Matriarx I've tried making several of the components memos, and even tried making my list item components the most basic possible PureComponent and ran into the same issue. I think what's super weird is the error didn't occur when I created a StackNavigator with just one screen for the "Catalog" page - but there's no reason to do this since the Catalog won't have multiple screens. Very weird.

Also, here's a video of the replication just incase this helps (the list items are a tad different than the original post): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kTneCRuLAYojTbcds0qvTPUfhl4B1yto/view

Comment: @Matriarx as you can see in the video, the list performance isn't bad or anything - so honestly I'm debating on whether or not I should just give up entirely on figuring this issue out and ignore the warning, or just go a different route instead of using a `FlatList`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old problem with `FlatLists` in React Native. FlatList in React Native is not known for its performance. However this could be mitigated by checking for unnecessary re-renders or nested components within the FlatList and making sure that your FlatList is not nested by a ScrollView. But you already stated that you are not re-rendering the list when returning to the screen and it is not nested by a ScrollView so it's probably the component itself.

Honestly I recently have had the same problem as you, but my FlatList is more complex than yours. When running it on a real device I noticed I haven't had a problem, for me this was only an issue on Expo Go. I've done my share of research but I haven't hit the nail on the head so I can only offer suggetions.

**Suggestion 1**

Check out this [RecyclerListView package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recyclerlistview), it seems very promising.

**Suggestion 2**

There is also this package, but I'm a bit skeptical about this one, I've heard complains [React Native Optimized Flatlist](https://github.com/st0ffern/react-native-optimized-flatlist) package. I'm pretty sure I tried it and it did nothing for me.

Also, check out these two pages on the topic:

- [FlatList Performance Tips](https://github.com/filipemerker/flatlist-performance-tips/)
- [GitHub Issue #13413](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13413)

Comment: Shopifys flashlist also came up during the last months - its also way more performant than FlatList and works in a similar way than RecyclerListView: 

https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to take a random shot at an answer, but it's at best a guess.

The video you've linked in the comments to your question made it a lot more clear what's happening, something strange is going on there.

With normal lists like those, especially on mobile, you want to render and load only the items that's currently being displayed and visible, you don't want to keep the entire list of all possible items in memory and rendered all the time.  That's why you'd use something like a callback to render the item, so that the list can invoke the callback as it's being scrolled and render only the items it needs to.

That being said here are a couple of random things I can think of:

- Make sure that every single component, including and especially the item component, are pure components so they don't rerender.  Make really sure that item component isn't rendering again.
- Try to alter your props destructure so that you directly receive the props, i.e. `({prop1, prop2})` instead of `props` with `...props`.  If you destructure the props like that it will create a new object every time an item is loaded.  This could potentially be one of the culprits causing your issue, if the flatlist is constantly invoking the callback and creating tons of new objects.  This could also potentially be an issue for the product item, if it sees that it's received a new prop reference, which means it's a different object, then it will have to do a shallow comparison (even if it's a pure component), on hundreds of props.  That could really slow it down.  The result is that it won't actually rerender it but it will still do hundreds of shallow object comparisons which is a slow process.  So fix the destructuring, I'd bet something like this is causing the performance issue.
- Make sure that you don't double render the view, don't render the flatlist before the data is actually loaded, before the state has been set only return the fallback spinner or loader and once the state has been set then return the full child.  Otherwise you're double rendering the whole thing, even if there's no data.
- Try and see if it makes a difference if you use an anonymous function as the renderItem callback, instead of using react class functions.  I don't think it should make a difference but it's worth a shot if nothing else helps, since I'm not sure how the renderItem is utilizing `this`.

If all else fails I'd suggest you ask react native on github and in the meantime try using an alternative if there is one.  On the other hand I don't really see any performance issues from the video, so perhaps it's also an error that can be safely ignored.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. Applying your tips did seem to make it take longer till I got the warning, but it still happened. I went to the extent of changing the renderItem to just a basic `Text` component with just the product name, and still encountered the same warning after some time. This is driving me crazy haha.

What's super weird is that when I create the `Stack.Navigator` with just one Screen and render that instead of the `CatalogScreen` the issue doesn't happen anymore. I guess this is a good enough workaround.

Comment: Since using a NativeStackNavigator with just 1 screen for the `CatalogScreen` component resolves the issue, I'm starting to think that this is an actual bug with the BottomTabNavigation module when combined with FlatLists. 

With that being said, I guess the best path forward is to use the NativeStackNavigator as a workaround (even though it seems pointless), and create a github issue.

Comment: I edited my original post if you want to see the workaround!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any more than that but I'm glad if you managed to get somewhere.

Comment: No worries at all man. Thank you for all the help, your suggestions did teach me something new.